# Jsoup doesn't work in android in the async task

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm trying to get html of a webpage and find all links present in this page using jsoup in android. I have added jsoup as external lib. Even tried adding it in libs folder. But I get "**unfortunately app stopped**"error. Can anyone help me please..

This is my MainActivity java code.

```
package com.example.asyncjsoup;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView textv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    new DownloadTask(textv).execute("http://www.karnatakatourism.org/");

    //Elements links=(Elements)link;
    //tv1.setText((CharSequence) b);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And this is the class where I have defined async task.

```
package com.example.asyncjsoup;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Elements>{


private TextView view;

public DownloadTask(TextView textvi)
{
    this.view=textvi;
}

 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
       // pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
       // pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
       // pDialog.setCancelable(false);
       // pDialog.show();
    }



    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected Elements doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String url = urls[0];
         Document doc;
         Elements links=null;

        try {
            //view.setText("this will be displayed in textview ");

            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            //view.setText("this wont be displayed in textview..i get unfortunately app stopped");
            links = doc.select("a[href]");


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return links;  
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Elements result) {
        print("\nLinks: (%d)", result.size());

        for (Element link : result) {
            view.setText((CharSequence) link);
            print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
        }

    }
    private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
        System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
    }

    private static String trim(String s, int width) {
        if (s.length() > width)
            return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
        else
            return s;
    }
}
```

I have added internet permission to my manifest file.

This is my logcat..

```
01-27 09:35:12.303: E/Trace(1293): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-27 09:35:12.303: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:12.303: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:12.303: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:12.723: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:12.763: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:13.533: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:13.533: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:13.543: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:13.573: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:13.704: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:13.713: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:13.723: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:13.863: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:13.863: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:13.875: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:13.875: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:13.875: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:13.875: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:13.913: D/gralloc_goldfish(1293): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-27 09:35:13.993: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:14.053: W/Trace(1293): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 09:35:15.704: D/dalvikvm(1293): GC_CONCURRENT freed 113K, 9% free 2653K/2888K, paused 78ms+4ms, total 143ms
01-27 09:35:15.704: D/dalvikvm(1293): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 55ms
01-27 09:35:18.573: D/dalvikvm(1293): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 333K, 19% free 2617K/3192K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
01-27 09:35:18.623: D/dalvikvm(1293): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 118K, 17% free 2676K/3192K, paused 47ms, total 47ms
01-27 09:35:19.423: D/dalvikvm(1293): GC_CONCURRENT freed 268K, 13% free 2806K/3192K, paused 82ms+81ms, total 225ms
01-27 09:35:19.943: D/dalvikvm(1293): GC_CONCURRENT freed 99K, 7% free 3115K/3336K, paused 72ms+73ms, total 203ms
01-27 09:35:20.713: D/dalvikvm(1293): GC_CONCURRENT freed 287K, 12% free 3213K/3616K, paused 72ms+83ms, total 224ms
01-27 09:35:21.493: D/dalvikvm(1293): GC_CONCURRENT freed 224K, 10% free 3385K/3728K, paused 73ms+84ms, total 226ms
01-27 09:35:22.383: D/dalvikvm(1293): GC_CONCURRENT freed 247K, 10% free 3528K/3888K, paused 77ms+76ms, total 245ms
01-27 09:35:23.244: D/dalvikvm(1293): GC_CONCURRENT freed 249K, 10% free 3674K/4040K, paused 84ms+95ms, total 281ms
01-27 09:35:23.613: I/System.out(1293): Links: (152)
01-27 09:35:23.613: D/AndroidRuntime(1293): Shutting down VM
01-27 09:35:23.623: W/dalvikvm(1293): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
01-27 09:35:23.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1293): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 09:35:23.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1293): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jsoup.nodes.Element cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
01-27 09:35:23.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.example.asyncjsoup.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:63)
01-27 09:35:23.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.example.asyncjsoup.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:1)
01-27 09:35:23.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
01-27 09:35:23.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-27 09:35:23.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
01-27 09:35:23.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 09:35:23.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 09:35:23.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-27 09:35:23.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 09:35:23.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 09:35:23.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-27 09:35:23.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-27 09:35:23.644: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 09:35:28.113: I/Process(1293): Sending signal. PID: 1293 SIG: 9
01-27 10:02:31.024: E/Trace(1490): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-27 10:02:31.024: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:31.024: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:31.024: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:31.546: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:31.583: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:32.335: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:32.335: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:32.353: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:32.374: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:32.553: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:32.563: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:32.573: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:32.768: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:32.774: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:32.804: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:32.804: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:32.813: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:32.813: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:32.833: D/gralloc_goldfish(1490): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-27 10:02:32.943: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:33.073: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:34.673: D/dalvikvm(1490): GC_CONCURRENT freed 90K, 8% free 2782K/2996K, paused 85ms+6ms, total 151ms
01-27 10:02:37.123: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:37.123: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:37.283: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:37.283: W/Trace(1490): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-27 10:02:37.703: D/dalvikvm(1490): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 451K, 21% free 2677K/3348K, paused 38ms, total 38ms
01-27 10:02:38.513: D/dalvikvm(1490): GC_CONCURRENT freed 267K, 17% free 2800K/3348K, paused 76ms+76ms, total 210ms
01-27 10:02:39.064: D/dalvikvm(1490): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 8% free 3093K/3348K, paused 76ms+84ms, total 220ms
01-27 10:02:39.773: D/dalvikvm(1490): GC_CONCURRENT freed 278K, 11% free 3207K/3600K, paused 76ms+78ms, total 227ms
01-27 10:02:40.573: D/dalvikvm(1490): GC_CONCURRENT freed 223K, 10% free 3378K/3716K, paused 78ms+89ms, total 236ms
01-27 10:02:41.393: D/dalvikvm(1490): GC_CONCURRENT freed 246K, 10% free 3522K/3884K, paused 82ms+90ms, total 258ms
01-27 10:02:42.083: D/dalvikvm(1490): GC_CONCURRENT freed 253K, 10% free 3665K/4036K, paused 76ms+80ms, total 247ms
01-27 10:02:42.443: I/System.out(1490): Links: (152)
01-27 10:02:42.443: D/AndroidRuntime(1490): Shutting down VM
01-27 10:02:42.443: W/dalvikvm(1490): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jsoup.nodes.Element cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at com.example.asyncjsoup.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:63)
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at com.example.asyncjsoup.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:1)
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 10:02:45.373: I/Process(1490): Sending signal. PID: 1490 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you post stacktrace/logcat output?

Comment: Have you added android.permission.INTERNET in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @RomanBlack i have given internet permission

Comment: from your log output thses are lines telling actual error 01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jsoup.nodes.Element cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at com.example.asyncjsoup.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:63)
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at com.example.asyncjsoup.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:1)

Comment: @Umar Qureshi : Can u suggest any solutions ?

Comment: It gives unfortunately stopped when it encounters Jsoup.connect(); The commented line textview.set("this will be displayed in testview") works if that comment line is removed..

Comment: From logcat it seams that you cannot cast Element to CharSequence. Replace this line
view.setText((CharSequence) link);
with this
view.setText(link.toString());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
01-27 09:35:23.64`enter code here`4: E/AndroidRuntime(1293): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jsoup.nodes.Element cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
```

this tells you cannot directly cast `Element` (of jsoup.nodes) to `CharSequnecne`.
However you can convert your `Element` to `string`, which can be directly used as a `CharSequence` without any cast;

So change your onPostExecute into something like this

```
protected void onPostExecute(Elements result) 
{
    print("\nLinks: (%d)", result.size());

    for (Element link : result) 
    {
        //view.setText((CharSequence) link);
        view.setText(link.toString());
        print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3230637 please mark mine or Umar Quereshi answer as solution

Answer (score 0):

Put jsoup.jar in your "libs" directory. Clean project and try again. Sometime there is problem when referencing libraries outside of project.

Also do not put this line in doInBackground. You can change this text field in onPostExecute only.

```
//view.setText("this wont be displayed in textview..i get unfortunately app stopped");
```

Answer (score 0):

From the following portion of log it's clear why you are facing this error

```
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490): java.lang.ClassCastException:       org.jsoup.nodes.Element cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at com.example.asyncjsoup.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:63)
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at com.example.asyncjsoup.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:1)
```

It is not the problem of adding Jsoup library as you have used classes from this library in your code and eclipse does not mentioned error so if it was library linkage error then eclipse have warned you about that...

Your log output clearly says that you are facing ClassCastException. From the name of this exception it is clear that your are trying to cast object of one class to the reference of another class which are not compatible. And it is also giving the case of casting which is causing this error

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Element cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
```

Which means you are trying to cast object of type Element(org.jsoup.nodes.Element) to the reference of type CharSequence(java.lang.CharSequence) which are not compatible with each other. From compatible here i mean that there is no parent child relation or interface implementation here which allows casting.

And more detail about error on below line

```
01-27 10:02:42.475: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at com.example.asyncjsoup.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:63)
```

This line clearly says that in your file "DownloadTask.java" at line 63 you are facing this ClassCastException. And from the above posted code of DownloadTask.java you can clearly see that line 63 is following (i just added numbers to your code here for just explanation)

```
 62  for (Element link : result) {
 63       view.setText((CharSequence) link);
 64       print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
 65   }
```

from here you can easily see that you are trying to cast object named as link(of Class Element) to the reference of CharSequence which are not compatible. if you want to display text of that node then you must find proper method of Class Element and REMEMBER here this Element class is not of DOM package i thing you are misunderstanding it here it is org.jsoup.nodes.Element (As you can see from import statements at the top of class DownloadTask). So to display text you must read documentation to find proper method which can return the proper string of text at that node.

here is link to documentation of class org.jsoup.nodes.Element http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html from a fast view i can say that data() or ownText() method of Element class is returning the string you are wanting. so if you modify the code of your line 63 to following then you can get what you want without error

```
 view.setText(link.data());
```

OR

```
view.setText(link.ownText());
```